# how to update local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar in android?

Tags: java, android, indexing, lucene, encryption

I have worked with the AES Directory for encrypt index Lucene.
on a desktop project I have this error :
InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: expected IV length of 16
So I have solved this problem by updating the two jar file local_policy. jar and US_export_policy. jar with JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.
Now I want to solve this problem in my android project! can I load or update this two jar in my android application ?